# Question Using Weierstrass Approximation Thm:

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \cdots , \lambda_m, \cdots $ be nonnegative, integrable functions on [0,1] with

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \lambda_k(x) dx  = 1$$

and

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_0^1 x^m \lambda_k(x) dx = 0$$ for $m=1,2, \cdots$

If $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ with  $f(0)=0$, show that for any $\epsilon > 0$,

$$\lim_{k \to \infty}|\int_0^1 f(x)\lambda_k dx| \leq 2\epsilon$$

My efforts: I know that by the WAT, we see for any $\epsilon >0$, there is a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $|f(x)-p(x)|< \epsilon$, which implies $\int_0^1|f(x)|dx - \int_0^1 |p(x)|dx . \leq \epsilon$.   I also know that $$\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_0^1 p(x)\lambda_k(x) dx = 0$$.

I'm don't know if these facts are useful in what I'm trying to show, or if I'm headed in the right direction, but I'd appreciate if someone could give me some guidance\ a hint here. Thanks!

Comment: You have $g$ there. Did you mean $f?$

Comment: Yes, I did! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Note that
$$
\left|\int_0^1 f(x)\lambda_k(x)dx\right|\le\int_0^1 |f(x)-p(x)|\lambda_k(x)dx+\left|\int_0^1 p(x)\lambda_k(x)dx\right|.
$$ The first term is bounded by $\epsilon$ as $k\to\infty$; $$\int_0^1 |f(x)-p(x)|\lambda_k(x)dx\le \int_0^1 \epsilon \lambda_k(x)dx \xrightarrow{k\to\infty}\epsilon.$$ And by the given condition, the second term converges to
$$
\left|\int_0^1 p(x)\lambda_k(x)dx\right|\xrightarrow{k\to\infty} |p(0)|= |p(0)-f(0)|\le \epsilon.
$$ Thus $\limsup_{k\to\infty}\left|\int_0^1 f(x)\lambda_k(x)dx\right|\le 2\epsilon.$